# How does the automatic equalizer in Music work?

Tags: music

I like it and am curious to know how it knows what to choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do anything special or particularly complicated. It just checks if the genre of the song is the same as the name of one of the equalizer presets. You can see the code in [Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/noise/trunk/view/head:/src/PlaybackManager.vala#L600)

Comment: More boring than I expected, but cool.